# Python Iterating through a list of float widths: TypeError: sequence expected, generator found

Tags: python, string, printing, width

I am trying to iterate through a list of float widths that varies.

```
[10.5, 15.5, 3.7]  <- Randomly generated
```

I am using this list of floats to generate spaces between a list of strings I am trying to print. I am doing this via

```
print ''.join('%*s' %i for i in zip(WIDTHS, LIST_OF_STRINGS))
```

I am getting the error

```
TypeError: sequence expected, generator found
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error?

EDIT: Python Version 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code in several ways. Now it works here (Python 2.7):

```
strings = ['a','b','c']
widths1 = [10, 15, 3]
widths2 = [5, 5, 7]
''.join('%*.*s' %i for i in zip(widths1, widths2, strings))
```

results in

```
'         a              b  c'
```

The width value in a format string is not a float, but two ints, separated by a `.`.

Answer (score 3):

You should actually get the error message

```
TypeError: * wants int
```

Convert your floating point numbers to ints first:

```
widths = map(int, widths)
```

Example:

```
>>> widths = [10.5, 15.5, 3.7]
>>> s = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> widths = map(int, widths)
>>> ''.join('%*s' %i for i in zip(widths, s))
'         a              b  c'
```